# Time Zone in the View Layer

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, timezone, presentation-layer

I'm writing my application with 'UTC' as the time zone. I have a `timezone` column for each user. I am going to use this value in the presentation layer. Date/time outputs and inputs will be using it.

I will also be presenting dates and times in the view layer when there's no current user. I want the fallback time zone to be the application one. I want to avoid putting logic like this every time:

```
$now = new Carbon();
if (!Auth::guest()) {
    $now->setTimezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
}
```

All this finally leads me to my question. Where/how is a good place to set the view layer time zone?

I'm providing my own answer, but I'm looking for better solutions, criticisms, etc.

Comment: Middleware that sets the `app.timezone` config at runtime, perhaps?

Comment: @ceejayoz - I don't want to change the application time zone, but I am intrigued about you pointing to using middleware. As a Laravel n00b, I'm not quite sure how middleware would be used. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Doing `config('app.timezone', 'Foo/Bar')` will only affect that one request - it won't affect the rest of the application or other pageviews. As for middleware, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Comment: @ceejayoz - I don't want to change it for the request either. I want the config value to remain always. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Set the session value during authentication (login)...

```
Auth::login($user);
session(['timezone', $user->timezone]);
```

Use it in the view layer...

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->setTimezone(session('timezone'))->format('h:i A T') }}
```